# Rename colnames according to data.frame

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have several data.frames `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, ... .

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var3 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var4 = c("a", "b", "c"))
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var3 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var4 = c("a", "b", "c"))
df3 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var3 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var4 = c("a", "b", "c"))
df4 <- data.frame(var1 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var2 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var3 = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  var4 = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

And I have a data.frame `rename_vars` which tells mich which variables in which data.frame should be renamed.

```
rename_vars <- data.frame(df = c("df1", "df1", "df3"), 
var = c("var1", "var3", "var1"), 
rename_to = c("var1x", "var3y", "var1z"))

   df  var rename_to
1 df1 var1     var1x
2 df1 var3     var3y
3 df2 var1     var1z
```

For example, in `df1` the variable `var1` should be renamed into `var1x` and `var3` should be called `var3x`. In data.frame `df2` variable `var1` should be called `var1z` and so forth.

But how can I automate this process of renaming variables in different data.frames according to `rename_vars`?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you meant the second element of rename_vars as 'df2'

Comment: yes, exactly. I corrected it.

Comment: Your `rename_vars` third element is 'df3' based o the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split the 'rename_vars' data based on the 'df' column then loop over the `list` with `map2` on the values from the `names` of the `list` (`mget`) and the 'lst1', and change the column names with `rename_at`.  It is better to keep it in a `list`, but if we need to change the global individual objects, use `list2env` after naming the `list` ('out') with the object names

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
lst1 <- split(rename_vars[-1], rename_vars$df)
out <- map2(mget(names(lst1)), lst1, ~ {
       nm1 <- .y[[1]]
       nm2 <- .y[[2]] 
       .x %>% 
         rename_at(vars(nm1), ~ nm2)})
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

-output

```
df1
#  var1x var2 var3y var4
#1     a    a     a    a
#2     b    b     b    b
#3     c    c     c    c

df3
#  var1z var2 var3 var4
#1     a    a    a    a
#2     b    b    b    b
#3     c    c    c    c
```

---

Or another option is `!!!` with `rename`

```
library(tibble)
lst1 <- split(as.list(deframe(rename_vars[3:2])), rename_vars$df)
list2env(map2(mget(names(lst1)), lst1, ~ .x %>% 
            rename(!!! .y)), .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or using `base R` with a `for` loop and `assign`

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(rename_vars))) {
   tmp1 <- get(rename_vars$df[i])
   i1 <- match(rename_vars$var[i], names(tmp1))
   names(tmp1)[i1] <- rename_vars$rename_to[i]
   assign(rename_vars$df[i], tmp1)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`setnames` from `data.table`

```
library('data.table')
for (dt in unique(rename_vars$df) ) {  
  df_rows <- (rename_vars$df == dt) # get row indices matching data frame name
  old <- rename_vars$var[df_rows] # old names
  new <- rename_vars$rename_to[df_rows] # new names
  setDT(get(dt)) # convert to data table by reference
  setnames(get(dt), old, new) # set names by reference
}
```

**Output:**

```
names(df1)
# [1] "var1x" "var2"  "var3y" "var4" 
names(df2)
# [1] "var1" "var2" "var3" "var4"
names(df3)
# [1] "var1z" "var2"  "var3"  "var4"
```